# Does removing a <charFilter> from solr schema.xml require a re-index?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, solrj

I have a solr 4.3.1 core that already has indexed data with the following configuration for a field in its schema.xml.  Here is the portion of my schema.xml related to the field, which is the "text" field.

```
<fields>
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
</fields>
<types>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>
```

I need to remove the `<charFilter>` part.  The `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` filter has a bug that makes it not usable in this scenario (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2834).  The bug makes the solrj client not able to handle the response from an analysis request to solr.  It is a bug in all versions of solr 4 as far as I can tell and it doesn't look like it is going to be fixed any time soon.  I also don't actually use the `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory`.  It was previously put in place but then never used.  As a result I have a blocking, unused feature in my schema that I want to remove.

I have a test environment with a copy of all of the data which I have experimented with.  In my test, I stopped the tomcat server that was running solr, removed that `<charFilter>` line, and restarted tomcat.  I did not see any negative impact from the change and now solrj is able to properly handle things and I get the results I am expecting.  At this point I feel like I can just make the change to schema.xml and that is all I need to do.

However, when I read pages like http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToReindex it makes it sound like I would need to reindex because I'm changing schema.xml.

So in the end, can anyone verify if I would need to re-index or not?  What are the risks, if any, to making this change to schema.xml without re-indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kinds of changes you make to schema.

If you make changes to schema.xml that apply to existing documents, you would need to reindex for those changes to be applied to your Solr index. You can change schema.xml and not reindex, but then at that point your index can become inconsistent, because new documents that you add to index will have updates.

In your example above, if you removed charFilter from schema.xml and do not reindex, the old documents already in the index will have charFilter applied to them while new ones getting indexed going forward would not have charFilter, so there will be an inconsistency. So it is recommended to reindex documents if changes apply to existing documents[already in index].

There are very rare use cases in which reindex is not required.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  So if I understand correctly, after the change in schema.xml things would still be functional (i.e. not throw errors either from the the solr webapp itself or the solrj client making requests to it) however there could be inconsistencies in what is indexed.  Is that accurate?  In my testing, everything looked functional and I did not see any errors.  But you make a good point about looking at what kind of inconsistency I might be introducing and how that impacts the useful of the index.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct, and inconsistencies will start showing up as you start indexing new documents along with old ones. If you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate if you can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me walk you thru the process on what's going on during indexing and querying so you understand the impact of not re-indexing.

Think of the flow into the index as a data pipeline, where modifications to the stream occur and then end up being written into the index. Some are pretty clear (like tokenizing on whitespace for example), others less so (like stemming tokenizers and filters). In any event this stream of data gets a combination of filters (which change data in place) and tokenizers (which break the stream into individual tokens) applied and ends with a series of tokens being stored in your index.

When you query you usually want the same set of filters and tokenizers, in the same order applied. Without that you would frequently have a mismatch. A classic example is using a stemming tokenizer on the way in, which will change the word "running" to "run". If you do not have the same stemming tokenizer in place when you query, "running" which will not be stemmed will not match documents with the word "running" in them, as their index has the stemmed version, "run", stored. Make sense so far?

When you change a field definition and don't re-index, queries now use a different tokenizer and filter change than that which was used for older data, so you run the risk of hitting the previous example.

So here's the general exception. If your filter never makes any changes to the data previously, removing it or adding it will not make a difference in your results. Let's say I had a custom filter that changed the string "ZZZZZ" into "AAAAA", and that's all it did. If I index a bunch of documents without "ZZZZZ" in them and then change the processing stream to remove my custom filter there is no real impact.

In your case you have been using the HTMLStripCharFilterFactory and are now pulling it out. If you had no HTML characters that would have been stripped, then removing it should have no impact.

Please note this is a big IF and verifying that it is true means examining every single document in your index. Not fun.

Please also note that it is generally a very, very bad idea to not reindex after changes like this.

With those two caveats, yes, this could work - but it will be a function of what's actually in your documents.

The risk is primarily at query time in being unable to find matching documents that were indexed prior to the change.

Comment: The detailed explanation definitely helps clarify what is happening with the indexing and querying.  My next step is to evaluate, as you mentioned, how the schema change would impact matching the documents that were indexed prior to the change.